# MySql :: Select multi variables

Tags: mysql, select

when I try to execute the following query :

```
SELECT filesinfo.IsFolder INTO @IsFolder, filesinfo.FileName 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE filesinfo.FileID = 1;
```

The following Error occurred :

> [**SQL**]  SELECT filesinfo.IsFolder INTO @IsFolder,
>   filesinfo.FileName FROM filesinfo WHERE filesinfo.FileID = 1; [Err]
>   1327 - **Undeclared variable: filesinfo**

But when remove the second parameter like this :

```
SELECT filesinfo.IsFolder INTO @IsFolder 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE filesinfo.FileID = 1;
```

no errors occurred

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: All right. What you want to achieve?

Comment: In fact  I need to select Some columns in a variables, i wrote this query to test the idea.

Comment: what a I want to now how can I select multi columns  in tables into variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this please, assuming you have delclared the variables properly and you have a column called FileName in the table..:

```
SELECT @IsFolder:=IsFolder, FileName 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE FileID = 1;
```

With full credit to @Mahmoud Gamal for giving me the SQLFIDDLE, please take a look at it to see live results of the query:

*** [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd1a/5)**

If you want to select multi columns you may declare multi variables and set them like the following:

```
SELECT @IsFolder:=IsFolder, @FileName:=FileName 
FROM filesinfo 
WHERE FileID = 1;
```